# jQuery: is delegating always better than direct functions binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, click

Is always better to use `$(document).on('click', selector, fn)` than `$(selector).click(fn)`, since the 1st choice:

1) can handle dynamically created element

2) is faster during page load.. right? (since JS doesn't have to spend time querying and binding function to each selector)

Is it safe to forget about direct binding and always go for delegation?

Comment: Not really... overuse of it will cause performance issues

Comment: I didn't research enough, but I presume both are equivalent. The browser will have to query the document to find the element on both scenarios, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Advantages

> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.
>
> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet  created, another advantage of delegated events is their potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be monitored.

Performance

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document
>   tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must
>   compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every
>   element in the path from the event target up to the top of the
>   document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document
>   location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive
>   use of document or document.body for delegated events on large
>   documents.

[`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler )

Answer (score 0):

With my research, I come to a conclusion that a good delegate method is better than the direct binding. Let's talk from the begging. We know that dom event will bubble up from the target element to it's parent, grandparent until to the `document`. Though there are a little difference among IE and other browsers, `Jquery event` creates consistent cross-browser behavior. Thus, the obvious difference between the two methods is that:

Direct bind event will occur on the target (or from its descendants) and bubble up to `document`, while delegation just bubble up to the outmost bind target. Consider the example:

```js
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
    console.log("button was clicked");
});

document.onclick = function(){
    console.log("document is clicked");
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv" style="background:darkgrey">
    <button type="button" id="testBtn">click me</button>
</div>
```

When click the button, `document.onclick` will be triggered.
However, if replace with the delegate method like:

```js
$("#myDiv").on("click", "#myBtn", function(){
    console.log("myBtn was clicked");
});
```

The `document.onclick` will not be triggered. Meanwhile, notice that click on the outmost `myDiv` will not trigger the event.

Here comes to the key point. Using the delegate method in a good manner will improve the performance hugely. See this example (mutated from *professional javascript for web developer*):

```html
<ul id="myLinks">
  <li id="goSomewhere"> Go somewhere </li>
  <li id="doSomething"> Do something </li> 
  <li id="sayHi"> Say hi </li>
</ul>
```

The traditional direct bind way would be:

```js
$("#goSomewhere").click(function(){
  window.location.href = "http://sample.com";  
});

$("#doSomething").click(function(){
  window.title = "I change the title";  
});

$("#sayHi").click(function(){
  alert("hi");  
});
```

If there are many click events, numbers of bind operation will consume a lot of memory as well as a long page initial time. We can subtract to just one bind operation with delegation:

```js
$("#myLink").on("click", function(event){
    switch(event.target.id){
      case: "goSomewhere":
         window.location.href = "http://sample.com";
         break;
      case: "doSomething":
        window.title = "title was changed";
        break;
      case: "sayHi":
         alert("hi");
        break;
    }
});
```

This reduce much memory to use. To be more practical, you may need to use a `object` to replace `switch-case` module for the performance, if there are lots of cases, like:

```js
var eventHandler = {
  goSomewhere: function(){ window.location = "http://sample.com"; },
  doSomething: function(){ window.title = "title changed"; },
  sayHi: function(){alert("hi"); }
}
$("#myLink").on("click", function(event){
  if(eventHandler[event.target.id]) eventHandler[event.target.id]();
});
```

Because javascript's object is actually a hash table.

Then, there comes an idea: just attach a single event to the `document` to handle all of the events. It's practical to events like mousedown, click, keydown and so on, not fit for mouseout, mousein. The advantage is clear: we just bind a event causing less memory, easy to remove the event handler, need not to wait for the document ready event as `document` has been be visible since it's child `script` is read. In contact, if you just bind every single event to `document`, the advantage will be gone.

Additionally, there is a trap if using direct bind, the example is from [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/on/): Considering a table with 1000 rows:

```js
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

This will attach a hander to 1000 `tr`! But the following one just a single attachment to `tbody`:

```js
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```